# heroku and gem only for dev environment 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, gemfile

In my gemfile I've got:

```
group :development do
gem 'eventmachine', "1.0.0.beta.4.1"
end
```

and in my gemfile.lock

```
DEPENDENCIES
eventmachine (= 1.0.0.beta.4.1)
```

When I try to push it to heroku it says that it can not find and istall eventmachine. But I don't need it on heroku server its for DEVELOPMENT environment. Why does it tries to install it? how should I handle this situation?

Comment: can you post the whole gemfile? you an try to do rm Gemfile.lock then regenerate it using bundler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran into this with SQLite. The solution is to keep requiring the gem in your source when in dev mode, but simply remove it from the Gemfile. The app will run on your dev machine cause event-machine is installed, but heroku will only install gems you tell it to in the Gemfile.

Comment: i think thats what the OP is doing except it's not working for him

Comment: Yes, Thanks, I just removed it from gemfile. But I thought that heroku won't look at "group development" in gemfile...

Comment: I've forgot I remove it from gemfile then when I run bundle install it tries to install eventmachine 0.12.10 - and it can not (there is not such version for windows. Its stupid. Why then there is env groups if they don't work??

Comment: Finally I've just written a script that comments gems that are not needed in production before adding, committing to git and pushing to heroku and then brings them back.

Answer (score 0):

I think heroku uses it's own eventmachine. Currently it has `eventmachine (0.12.10)` installed so that's the version you should use.

Comment: there is no 0.12.10 version for Windows (